# To display the array data as a list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am displaying the data i,e month,name,time from an array called Batch.
As shown in below image.

[image]

Suppose if i add more data to array (Batch).It as to display the new data one below the other like this

[image]

Here is the forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-scg3ah) link.How can i do this?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or are you asking how to push items to array?

Comment: Now i have added only one month,name,time if i add more than these.it as to display as i mentioned in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `*ngFor` single  time in parent div

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/to-display-the-array-data-as-a-list?file=app/demo/demo.component.html)**

```
<div>
  <h2 class="ylet-primary-500 alignleft">Sessions</h2>
  <p class="alignright"><mat-icon class="ylet-primary-500">add_circle_outline</mat-icon></p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div *ngFor="let batch of batches">
<div>
  <h3 class="classes"  >{{batch.month}}
    <span class="chips">


    </span>
  </h3>
  <p class="ylet-primary-500 booking"><a>Book now</a></p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
  <p class="timings">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>access_time</mat-icon><span >{{batch.time}}</span>
     <span class="slots" > <mat-icon>list_alt</mat-icon>{{batch.slots}}</span>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got it, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating three `ngFor` loops for displaying each property, use one `ngFor` but on a parent element. [Something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-wwgx6o).

Comment: Thank you, now i came to know where i did mistake.

Comment: Like passing the name, month i,e `{name: 'Regular 2', month: 'September 3', time: '12:30 PM - 5:00 PM' , slots: '5/25' } ` can i give different color for each array item??

Comment: Sure. Just add it as a property to the object. `{name: 'Regular 2', month: 'September 3', time: '12:30 PM - 5:00 PM' , slots: '5/25', color: '#aaa' }`

Comment: I tried,but i was unable to do.Previously i defined name, month as string.How can i define a color?

Comment: I've updated the [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-wwgx6o) to include a color. That's just something quick. Is that what you meant?